# Search for specific item from axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, search

New to programming in React. Using api axios i've retrieved weather information. What i'm trying to do is if a user select a specific city from the drop down list i want the weather information for that city to be shown - to be honest i've researched but not sure how to go about code.
Is there anyone can direct me. At the moment if i hard code a city i get weather on the api url i get the information but i want users to be able to choose any location from the drop down list specified.
My code so far:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

import { useState } from "react";

function App({ searchCities }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${searchCities}&units=metric&appid=08acd577f8ab8cabf637f7cd3736a629`;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setCity(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [searchCities]);

  const [newSearchTerm, setNewSearchTerm] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) =>{
    setNewSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      searchCities(newSearchTerm);
      setNewSearchTerm('');
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Still Loading be patient</h2>;
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <select name="city">
            <option value="0">Choose the City</option>
            <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
            <option value="London">London</option>
          </select>
          <h3>Humidity: {city.main.humidity}</h3>
          <h3>Temp: {city.main.temp}</h3>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { useState } from "react";

function App({ searchCities }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const getWeatherData = (selectedCity) => {
    if (selectedCity) {
      const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${selectedCity}&units=metric&appid=08acd577f8ab8cabf637f7cd3736a629`;
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        setWeatherData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {}, [searchCities]);

  const [newSearchTerm, setNewSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setCity(event.target.value);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (city) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      getWeatherData(city);
    }
  }, [city]);
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    /* event.preventDefault();
      searchCities(newSearchTerm);
      setNewSearchTerm(''); */
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Still Loading be patient</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <select name="city" onChange={handleChange}>
              <option value="0">Choose the City</option>
              <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
              <option value="London">London</option>
            </select>
            <h3>Humidity: {weatherData?.main.humidity}</h3>
            <h3>Temp: {weatherData?.main.temp}</h3>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Fantastic it works perfectly as ow i wanted it. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly for what i'm wanting

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `onChange` prop to the `select` element and pass it a handler function that would update the `city` state, the handler function would be:

```js
const handleCityChange = (e) => {
  setSelectedCity(e.target.value);
  // ...
};
```

Another thing I would suggest you is instead of using a *selectable* *option* "*Choose the City*" you can make it the "*default*" option by setting the initial value of `city` value to be `"default"` and the first option would have this `value="default"` and pass it a [`disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp) prop to make it unselectable:

```js
// ...
const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState("default");
// ...
<select name="city" value={selectedCity} onChange={handleCityChange}>
  <option value="default" disabled>Choose the City</option>
// ...
```

**EDIT2:** I noticed you are using `setCity` for the *data* received, so I have created another `selectedCity` state.

The final code would look like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

import { useState } from "react";

function App({ searchCities }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState("default");


  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${searchCities}&units=metric&appid=08acd577f8ab8cabf637f7cd3736a629`;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setCity(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [searchCities]);

  const [newSearchTerm, setNewSearchTerm] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) =>{
    setNewSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      searchCities(newSearchTerm);
      setNewSearchTerm('');
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Still Loading be patient</h2>;
  }

// Define handleCityChange function
  const handleCityChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedCity(e.target.value);
 
    // Make HTTP request when city is changed
    axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${e.target.value}&units=metric&appid=08acd577f8ab8cabf637f7cd3736a629`)
    .then((response) => {
      setCity(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <select name="city" value={selectedCity} onChange={handleCityChange}>
            <option value="default" disabled>Choose the City</option>
            <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
            <option value="London">London</option>
          </select>
          <h3>Humidity: {city.main.humidity}</h3>
          <h3>Temp: {city.main.temp}</h3>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How very detail explanation - work perfectly. Thank you for the solution

Comment: You may tick an answer as accepted, *mine or the other*, whoever helped, so that people would know your issue is fixed.